# Proving a logarithm inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$$\frac{1}{n+1}< \log(1+ 1/n)$$

Any ideas? I tried estimating the difference between $1/n$ and the logarithm and comparing with $1/n-1/(n+1)$ but I miserably failed.

Comment: Did you try considering the function $f(x)=\log(1+x^{-1})-(x+1)^{-1}$?

Comment: Well I suppose I could do that, but this was an exercise after a chapter on successions and series, so I don't think it would be fair.

Comment: You can write the right hand side as $\log \frac{n+1}{n}$, maybe that gives you an idea.

Comment: Taylor series?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Try integrating 1/x over a suitable range. Maybe still not fair though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$
(n+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)>1
$$
or
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}>e
$$
which is known to be true: it's usually part of the definition of $e$ by means of sequences.

Comment: makes sense. thank you.

Comment: Could you please give more explanation. I know that the definition is usually

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n} = \mathrm{e}$$

Comment: @FlybyNight If you change the exponent to $n+1$, you get a decreasing sequence converging to $e$, and $(1+1/n)^n<e<(1+1/n)^{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Using the integral definition of the logarithm you have, for $n>0$,
$$
\log(1+\frac1n)=\int_1^{1+\frac1n}\,\frac{1}x\,dx>\int_1^{1+\frac1n}\frac1{1+\frac1n}\,dx=\frac{\frac1n}{1+\frac1n}=\frac1{n+1}
$$
(note that the inequality is strict because $1/x$ is monotone and non-constant).

Comment: You need to disprove equality.

Comment: The inequality is strict because $1/x$ is monotone and non-constant.

Comment: Thanks for making the improvement. A very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I'm editing the answer to include mention of that.

Answer (score 3):

We apply the mean value theorem to the function $\log$ on the interval $\left(1,1+\frac1n\right)$: 
$$\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\frac1n\frac1c$$
where
$$1<c<1+\frac1n\Rightarrow \frac1c>\frac n{n+1}$$
so we conclude that
$$\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)>\frac 1{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Mean Value Theorem over an interval [1,x] of log(x)